# How to test function that call api with jest and redux saga

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

I need to test redux saga with jest. But it's not working. Here is what I tried

service.js

```
class Login {
    login = async (user: any) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                url: `${API.BASE_URL}signIn`,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    LoginID: user.LoginID,
                    Password: user.Password,
                }),
            });
            return Bluebird.resolve(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            return Bluebird.reject(err);
        }
    }
}

export default new Login();
```

worker.js

```
export function* loginWorker(action) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(service.login, action.payload);
        if (response.Success) {
            yield put({type: actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION, response});
        } else {
            toastr.showToast(response.Message);
            yield put({type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE', response});
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // dispatch a failure action to the store with the error
        yield put({type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE', err});
        toastr.showToast(err);
    }
}
```

test.js

```
describe('test login', () => {
    const action = {
        type: actionTypes.LOGIN_ACTION,
        payload: user,
    };
    it('login', () => {
        const gen = loginWorker(action);
        expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(service.login, action.payload));
        expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(put({type: actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS_ACTION, response}));
    });
});
```

But this function service.login not to be called and I get this error

```
Cannot read property 'Success' of undefined
```

Where is my wrong? Please help

Comment: is it possible that the `login promise` throws a `rejection`? can you try to use `console.log` in the login API? `console.log(response)` and `console.log(err)` in the `service.js`

Comment: @kkesley it's still not running

Comment: I mean what do you see when you `console.log(response` and `console.log(err)` in your login handler?

Comment: @kkesley this function is not running so nothing in `console.log`

Comment: how about `console.log(service.login)`? does it reflect the actual function?

Comment: Is there any solution for this? I also want to test for redx-saga generators which calls api